# Evaluar una condición en un Foreach con ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist, condiciones, foreach

tengo el siguiente ArryList de una clase Producto el cual tiene variable nombre y codigo, y un metodo getCodigo().

```
ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();

    listaProductos.add("pantalon", "p01");
    listaProductos.add("Poleron", "p02");
    listaProductos.add("Lechuga", "veg01");
```

El usuario ingresara un codigo y quiero evaluar si ese codigo existe o no en el Array.

```
System.out.println("Por favor ingrese el codigo del producto");
String codigoProducto = entrada.nextLine();
            
        for (Producto productos : listaProductos) {
                                            
            if(codigoProducto.equals(productos.getCodigo())){
                System.out.println("Existe");
            }else {
                System.out.println("No existe");
            }}
```

Si ingreso un codigo erroneo, me muestra

```
No existe
No existe
No existe
```

Y si ingreso un codigo correcto, por ejemplo veg01, me muestra:

```
No existe
No existe
Existe
```

Como puedo solucionar eso? Si existe el elemento quiero que me muestre "Existe" y termine el ciclo, y si no existe despues de evaluar todos los elementos, solo me muestre un "No existe" y no 3. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que estás cometiendo es que estás imprimiendo por cada item de la lista. Deberías calcular una bandera para saber si hay o no hay y luego imprimir.

Clasico:

```
boolean esta=false;
for (Producto producto: listaProductos) {
    if (producto.getCodigo().equals(codigoProducto)) {
        esta=true;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(esta ? "Existe" : "No existe");
```

La forma con streams, lo que da un código mas corto es:

```
boolean esta = listaProductos.stream().anyMatch(producto -> producto.getCodigo().equals(codigoProducto));

System.out.println(esta ? "Existe" : "No existe");
```